# Ajax only gives data after page reload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a notification button for an inactive article for my blog and I don't want admin to reload his/her page to see a new inactive article submitted, so I want to do this with AJAX.

I prepend html data to:
`<ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list" role="menu">`

But my code only loads an new result after page reload.
Also, the each loop is repeating same data 2 times.

What's going wrong?

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'inc/file.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response)
    {
        if (response) {

            var html = '';
            $.each(response, function(key, value){
                html += "<li><a href='editArticle?id="+response.id+"&amp;act='><span>"+response.title+"</span><span>"+response.story+"</span></a></li>";

            })
            $('#menu1').prepend(html);
            $('#number').text(response.number);

        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Here is my file.php while is fetching only one data:

```
<?php 

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/init.php';

require CLASS_PATH.'article.php';

$article = new Article();

$list = $article->getInactiveArticle();
$number = $article->countInactiveArticle();

$output = [];
foreach ($list as $lists) {
    $output['title'] = $lists->title;
    $output['id'] = $lists->id;
    $output['story'] = $lists->story;
    $output['number'] = $number[0]->inactive_articles;
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: You should try `websocket` or similar real-time data providers to use Facebook like notification and updates.

Comment: Regarding your second issue: what is the value of `response`? Is it an array of objects? Depending on the data's structure, you might want to be using `value.id` and `value.title`, etc.

Comment: @showdev I have edited my code. I am only getting one data in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test  the following code block.

It checks every 5 seconds and performs the operations.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var eint = window.setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'inc/file.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response)
            {
                if (response) {

                    var html = '';
                    $.each(response, function(key, value){
                        html += "<li><a href='editArticle?id="+response.id+"&amp;act='><span>"+response.title+"</span><span>"+response.story+"</span></a></li>";

                    })
                    $('#menu1').prepend(html);
                    $('#number').text(response.number);

                }
            }
        });
    },5000);
)};
```

Comment: yes the code checks in every 5 secs but it keep on appending to the same data after 5 secs. I mean I have 3 data and after 5 secs I am getting 6 data.

Comment: Try this way. $('#menu1').html(html);

Comment: @Alisha Note that you are using [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), which adds to the existing content rather than replacing it.

Comment: @Tuncay BAŞ yes, I got that but I same data is being repeated. I mean I am only getting data of id 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `setTimeout()` function.

```js
function timeout() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $.ajax...

    timeout()
  }, 3000);

}
```

[Have a look docs here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: He would want setInterval not setTimeout,

Comment: Maybe, but Lalabuy is calling `timeout()` again from within the AJAX call. I guess this might help avoid overlapping timeouts if the AJAX call should take more than 3 seconds.